# How to set the server variable on the fly using capistrano 3

Tags: capistrano3

we're trying to make our deployment scripts as generic as possible.  Is it possible to have capistrano 3 prompt for the server address rather than setting it in the config files.

So far  i have a capistrao task that does

```
namespace :config do
  task :setup do
    ask(:db_user, 'db_user')
    ask(:db_pass, 'db_pass')
    ask(:db_name, 'db_name')
    ask(:db_host, 'db_host')
    ask(:application, 'application')
    ask(:web_server, 'server')
    setup_config = <<-EOF
#{fetch(:rails_env)}:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: #{fetch(:db_name)}
  username: #{fetch(:db_user)}
  password: #{fetch(:db_pass)}
  host: #{fetch(:db_host)}
    EOF
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"
      upload! StringIO.new(setup_config), "#          {shared_path}/config/database.yml"
        end
      end
    end
```

and in my production.rb file i have

```
set :application, "#{fetch(:application)}"
set :server_name, "#{fetch(:application)}.#{fetch(:server)}"
set :app_port, "80"
```

But when I do cap production config:setup to run the config script I get an error asking me for a password.  If  i hard code the server address in the production.rb file it works fine...how can I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I hope that someone else offers a more elegant solution, but if not:

I've done this in some cases with environment variables. If you want, you can also use a Makefile to simplify some of the env combinations.